Adapt Code to Solve Fractional-Order System Delay Differential Equations- Chen System
Dynamics of fractional-ordered Chen system with delay
I have tried to modify this code
`a1 = 35;
b1 = 3;
c1 = 27;
x0 = 0.2; y0 = 0; z0 = 0.5;


v = 0.97;
T = 10;
h = 0.005;

\[Tau] = 0.005;

(*FABM*)

Module[{a, b, c}, a = a1; b = b1; c = c1; nt = Round[T/h];
  m = Ceiling[v];
  k = 1; 
  While[k <= 
    nt, \[Rho][k] = (k)^v - (k - 1)^v; \[Sigma][
     k] = (k + 1)^(v + 1) - 2 (k)^(v + 1) + (k - 1)^(v + 1); k++];
  x[0] = x0;
  y[0] = y0;
  z[0] = z0;
  arraytx = {}; arrayty = {};
  arraytz = {};
  arrayqy = {};
  arraypx = {}; arrayrz = {}; arraypq = {}; arraypr = {}; 
  arrayqr = {}; arraypqr = {};
  arrayxy = {}; arrayxz = {}; arrayyz = {}; arrayxyz = {};
  j = 1; While[j <= nt + 1, t = j*h;
   p[j] = 
    x[0] + h^v/
       Gamma[v + 1]*(Sum[\[Rho][j - k]*(a*(y[k] - x[k - \[Tau]])), {k,
          0, j - 1}]);
   q[j] = 
    y[0] + h^v/
       Gamma[v + 
         1]*(Sum[\[Rho][
          j - k]*((c - a)*x[k - \[Tau]] - x[k]*z[k] + c*y[k]), {k, 0, 
         j - 1}]);
   r[j] = 
    z[0] + h^v/
       Gamma[v + 
         1]*(Sum[\[Rho][j - k]*(x[k]*y[k] - b*z[k - \[Tau]]), {k, 0, 
         j - 1}]);
   x[j] = 
    x[0] + h^v/
       Gamma[v + 
         2]*(a*(q[j] - 
           p[j - \[Tau]]) + ((j - 1)^(v + 1) - (j - 1 - v)*
            j^v)*(a*(y[0] - x[0]))) + 
     h^v/Gamma[
        v + 2]*(Sum[\[Sigma][j - k]*(a*(y[k] - x[k - \[Tau]])), {k, 1,
          j - 1}]);
   y[j] = 
    y[0] + h^v/
       Gamma[v + 
         2]*(((c - a)*p[j - \[Tau]] - p[j]*r[j] + 
          c*q[j]) + ((j - 1)^(v + 1) - (j - 1 - v)*j^v)*((c - a)*
            x[0] - x[0]*z[0] + c*y[0])) + 
     h^v/Gamma[
        v + 2]*(Sum[\[Sigma][
          j - k]*((c - a)*x[k - \[Tau]] - x[k]*z[k] + c*y[k]), {k, 1, 
         j - 1}]);
   z[j] = 
    z[0] + h^v/
       Gamma[v + 
         2]*((p[j]*q[j] - 
          b*r[j - \[Tau]]) + ((j - 1)^(v + 1) - (j - 1 - v)*
            j^v)*(x[0]*y[0] - b*z[0])) + 
     h^v/Gamma[
        v + 2]*(Sum[\[Sigma][j - k]*(x[k]*y[k] - b*z[k - \[Tau]]), {k,
          1, j - 1}]);
   
   arraytx = Append[arraytx, {t, x[j]}];
   arrayty = Append[arrayty, {t, y[j]}];
   arraytz = Append[arraytz, {t, z[j]}];
   arraypx = Append[arraypx, {t, p[j]}];
   arrayqy = Append[arrayqy, {t, q[j]}];
   arrayrz = Append[arrayrz, {t, r[j]}];
   (*arraypq=Append[arraypq,{p[j],q[j]}];
   arraypr=Append[arraypr,{p[j],r[j]}];
   arrayqr=Append[arrayqr,{q[j],r[j]}];
   arraypqr=Append[arraypqr,{p[j],q[j],r[j]}];
   arrayxy=Append[arrayxy,{x[j],y[j]}];
   arrayxz=Append[arrayxz,{x[j],z[j]}];
   arrayyz=Append[arrayyz,{y[j],z[j]}];*)
   arrayxyz = Append[arrayxyz, {x[j], y[j], z[j]}];
   (*Put[arraytx,"arraytx"];
   Put[arraypx,"arraypx"];
   Put[arrayty,"arrayty"];
   Put[arrayqy,"arrayqy"];
   Put[arraytz,"arraytz"];
   Put[arrayrz,"arrayrz"];
   Put[arraypq,"arraypq"];
   Put[arraypr,"arraypr"];
   Put[arrayqr,"arrayqr"];
   Put[arraypqr,"arraypqr"];
   Put[arrayxy,"arrayxy"];
   Put[arrayxz,"arrayxz"];
   Put[arrayyz,"arrayyz"];
   Put[arrayxyz,"arrayxyz"];*)j++];
  Put[arraytx, "tx-FABM"];
  Put[arrayty, "ty-FABM"];
  Put[arraytz, "tz-FABM"];
  Put[arrayxyz, "xyz-FABM"]];
Print[ListLinePlot[{Get["tx-FABM"]},
   
   
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]];
Print[ListPointPlot3D[{Get["xyz-FABM"]},
   
   
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]];`

to get the attached figures from the paper, but when I add the /Tau (delay), the code is not running even though I have waited for it to run for almost 24 hours. I tried to use the chat-notebook in the Mathematica notebook, but since the numerical method is used in the code and it requires deeper knowledge, it suggested me to ask the experts who can be in this group
This is the Chen system with parameters a=35, b=3, c= 27, and the figures that must be presented      
Thank you in advance and greatly appreciate your contribution!

There is a famous quote that says ""Premature optimization is the root of all evil". In this case it is definitely not premature. Each iteration gets slower and slower.

Some advice: do not use single square brackets except to provide arguments to functions. To set the element j of "array" p you use the p[[j]]=... notation with double square brackets. That will be faster than creating a zillion replacement rules. Type DownValues[\[Rho]] after the 1st While loop to understand what you are doing.

Additionally, initialize your arrays (like p, q, x, y, z) using ConstantArray and be careful that the 1st element is element number 1 and not 0. With these changes it will run much faster.

I did the suggestions in my notebook but it's still running (almost 10 hours), can you try to find the problem by trying the code in your notebook?
